# sql: need to move null values in date column to right and not nulls to left

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table containing customer name and their address

```
CUSTOMERNAME    ADD1    ADD2    ADD3    ADD4
JONY            NULL    No      No      1   
JEMMY           1       NULL    No      2   
JOOJOO          1       No      No      3   
JEREMY          NULL    NULL    No      1   
JOCKY           1       No      NULL    2   
Jack            1       No      No      NULL
```

Requirement is to shift all the null from address to left (from add1 towards add4) and bring not null columns up.

EG:

```
CUSTOMERNAME    ADD1    ADD2    ADD3    ADD4
JONY            NULL    No      No      1
```

Output:

```
CUSTOMERNAME    ADD1    ADD2    ADD3    ADD4
JONY            No      No      1       NULL
```

I have tried using case along with NVL but the approach doesn't look correct .

```
select nvl(nvl(nvl(add1,add2),add3),add4) as add1_mod ,
case when add1 is not null  then nvl(nvl(add2,add3),add4)
else add4  end as add2_mod
from test a;
```

This approach looks incorrect as this will create a bulky and irrelevant query.

Can someone please suggest me better approach..

Comment: Looks like a very bad table design.

Comment: yeah but that is the requirement :)

Comment: A PL/SQL block is more suited to achieve what you want to do

Comment: yes we can, but that is not preferable specialty in case of Enterprise Data warehouse environment where data is huge and loaded frequently

Answer (score 2):

If you're on 11g or higher you could unpivot the columns to rows, which 'loses' the null values, while keeping track of their original order:

```
select customername, addr,
  row_number() over (partition by customername order by colnum) as rn
from test
unpivot (addr for colnum in (add1 as 1, add2 as 2, add3 as 3, add4 as 4))

CUSTOMERNAME ADDR         RN
------------ ---- ----------
JEMMY        1             1
JEMMY        No            2
JEMMY        2             3
JEREMY       No            1
JEREMY       1             2
JOCKY        1             1
...
```

and then pivot that back:

```
select *
from (
  select customername, addr,
    row_number() over (partition by customername order by colnum) as rn
  from test
  unpivot (addr for colnum in (add1 as 1, add2 as 2, add3 as 3, add4 as 4))
)
pivot (max(addr) as addr for (rn) in (1 as a, 2 as b, 3 as c, 4 as d))
```

Demo with a CTE for your sample data, and renaming the pivoted columns back to their original names:

```
with test (CUSTOMERNAME, ADD1, ADD2, ADD3, ADD4) as (
  select cast('JONY' as varchar2(12)), cast(NULL as varchar2(4)),
    cast('No' as varchar2(4)), cast('No' as varchar2(4)), cast('1' as varchar2(4))
    from dual
  union all select 'JEMMY', '1', NULL, 'No', '2' from dual
  union all select 'JOOJOO', '1', 'No', 'No', '3' from dual
  union all select 'JEREMY', NULL, NULL, 'No', '1' from dual
  union all select 'JOCKY', '1', 'No', NULL, '2' from dual
  union all select 'Jack', '1', 'No', 'No', NULL from dual
)
select customername, a_addr as add1, b_addr as add2, c_addr as add3, d_addr as add4
from (
  select customername, addr,
    row_number() over (partition by customername order by colnum) as rn
  from test
  unpivot (addr for colnum in (add1 as 1, add2 as 2, add3 as 3, add4 as 4))
)
pivot (max(addr) as addr for (rn) in (1 as a, 2 as b, 3 as c, 4 as d))
order by customername;

CUSTOMERNAME ADD1 ADD2 ADD3 ADD4
------------ ---- ---- ---- ----
JEMMY        1    No   2        
JEREMY       No   1             
JOCKY        1    No   2        
JONY         No   No   1        
JOOJOO       1    No   No   3   
Jack         1    No   No
```

This is likely to be more expensive than Aleksej's approach, but it's an option to consider, and you can always evaluate both (and others that come up) to see which is best for your data.

Answer (score 1):

This shoud be the logic you need:

```
select CUSTOMERNAME,
       coalesce(ADD1, ADD2, ADD3, ADD4) as ADD1,
       case
         when ADD1 is not null then coalesce (ADD2, ADD3, ADD4)
         when ADD2 is not null then coalesce (ADD3, ADD4) 
         when ADD3 is not null then ADD4                  
       end as ADD2,
       case
         when ADD1 is not null and ADD2 is not null then coalesce(ADD3, ADD4)
         when ADD1 is not null OR ADD2 is not null and ADD3 is not null then ADD4
       end as ADD3,
       case
         when ADD1 is not null and ADD2 is not null and ADD3 is not null then ADD4
       end as ADD4
from test
```

This is based on how `CASE` works, both using the value of the first matched condition

```
SQL> select case
  2          when 1=1 then 1
  3          when 2=2 then 2
  4         end
  5  from dual;

CASEWHEN1=1THEN1WHEN2=2THEN2END
-------------------------------
                              1
```

and returning `NULL` when no condition is matched

```
SQL> select nvl( case when 1=9 then 1  end, 999)
  2  from dual;

NVL(CASEWHEN1=9THEN1END,999)
----------------------------
                         999
```

The result:

```
CUSTOMERNAME    ADD1  ADD2  ADD3  ADD4
--------------- ----- ----- ----- -----
JONY            No    No    1
JEMMY           1     No    2
JOOJOO          1     No    No    3
JEREMY          No    1
JOCKY           1     No    2
Jack            1     No    No
```